# Colored Image Steganography in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, rgb, steganography

I have made a steganography algorithm in matlab to hide colored image inside another colored image. The probelm is the extracted image isn't same as the original secret image.

The idea of algorithm is taking the pixel from secret image and split it into 4 groups of 2 bits, then put each 2 bits instead of the least significant 2 bits of cover pixel. This is the code below:

```
clear;
clc;
cover = imread('colored.jpg');
secret = imread('c4.png');

row = size(secret,1);
col = size(secret,2);
col = col -mod(col, 4);

if size(cover, 1) < row*4 || size(cover, 2) < col*4
    error('Cover image is too small to hide the hidden image.');
end

disp(size(secret));

for i=1:row
    for j=1:4:col
        for k=1:3
            sbyte = secret(i,j,k);
            sbyte = dec2bin(sbyte, 8);
            start=1;
            for l=j:j+3
                cbyte = cover(i,l,k);
                cbyte = dec2bin(cbyte, 8);
                seg = sbyte(start:start+1);
                cbyte(end-1:end) = seg;
                cbyte = bin2dec(cbyte);
                cover(i,l,k) = cbyte;
                start = start+2;
            end
        end
    end
end

imwrite(cover, 'stego_image.png');

disp('----------');

hidden = zeros(size(secret));


stego = imread('stego_image.png');

for i=1:row
    for j=1:4:col
        for k=1:3
            sbyte = '';
            for l=j:j+3
                cbyte = stego(i,l,k);
                cbyte = dec2bin(cbyte, 8);
                sbyte = strcat(sbyte, cbyte(end-1:end));
            end
            hidden(i,j,k) = bin2dec(sbyte);
        end
    end
end


disp(size(hidden));

hidden = uint8(hidden) .* secret;
imshow(hidden);
```

The output should be the same as origianl secret image but I got:
[hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDlIO.jpg)

Comment: You’re only reading one of every four pixels of `secret`.

Comment: I would reduce complexity of your code by reshaping the two input arrays to 1D, then it’s just a single loop over bytes. You also need the cover image to have 4 times as many bytes as the secret, your test verifies it has 16 (4x4) times as many!

Comment: can you give me the whole code for it with details please? @CrisLuengo